# Unable to upload Files greater than 4KB Websphere

Tags: file-upload, websphere-8, apache-commons-fileupload

I have a web application which uploads a file and parses the data in it. However, I am not able to upload the files which are larger than 4 KB. When I click on the submit button nothing happens. I even checked the `plugin-cfg.cml` under `my_profile/config/cells`. The `PostSizeLimit` is set to -1. Is there any other solution for it?
I am using Websphere Application server 8.0. Somebody please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Is the web server pointing to the same plugin-cfg.xml? If yes keep in mind that network performance and TTL also play some role in this.